# Fail background-image when send a mail

Tags: php, html, css, email, phpmailer

I have send a mail with a template html.
i'm using phpmailer class.
My code is like this

```
<td style="display:block;background-image:url('my_image.jpg')">
```

this template have a background-image that work in Gmail, but when i send to a mail from the work (@minem.gov.ar) this fail and my code html is come as

```
<td style="display:block;background-image:">
```

thank everybody and sorry for my poor english

Comment: @walkingRed, This is not a duplicate of that Q - the OP is not asking to embed an image but reference an external one from an inline style.

Comment: Try using absolute path of image and image should be accessible publicly;

Comment: my image is https://www.se.gob.ar/alarmas/HTMLs/images/back_cumple_02.jpg

Comment: @itzmukeshy7 i try with url(https://....) and not work

Comment: @Synchro my bad. But still referencing image is bad idea. Most clients have blocked by default remote files.

Comment: @HernánDanielGarau This link don't allow hotlinks and returns error `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`

Comment: Sure, but that's a different question. Also worth noting is that background images do not work at all in Outlook, so they are really worth avoiding.

Comment: ok, thank everybody. i have talk with designer for change the template

Comment: i can add point reputation for you help?... how?